# Number of components of topological space

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Consider the topological space $\mathbb{R}$ and the subset $\mathbb{Q}$ which has as many components as elements and is therefore totally unconnected. Now consider the product space $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. How many components does the product space have? I would assume it's |$\mathbb{Q}$|^2, because we have |$\mathbb{Q}$|^2 elements which are totally unconnected. I'm not quite sure if I got it right, and do understand how the number of components translates into the product space in general.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb Q \times  \mathbb Q $ is also countable.

Comment: Aside from the question about cardinality, in general if we call $\pi(X)$ is the set of connected components of the topological space $X$, then $\pi(X\times Y)=\{A\times B\,:\, A\in\pi(X)\land B\in \pi(Y)\}$. More generally, $\pi\left(\prod_{j\in J}X_j\right)=\left\{\prod_{j\in J}A_j\,:\, \forall j, A_j\in\pi(X_j)\right\}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$

Comment: So if the number connected components in $\pi(X)$ is 3 and $\pi(Y)$ is 2, then the product space will have 6 connected components?